# Upload file without form (Laravel)

Tags: image, api, rest, laravel, uploading

I'm trying to write REST API to laravel 5.1. How to upload a file (image) on server without form and views?

I tried to get out of the body of the request and convert it to a resource, but also get a line image.

```
$image = Request::getContent();
$i = imagecreatefromstring($image);
imagejpeg($i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CURL` with [curl_file_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-file-create.php):

```
$file = '/foo/bar/img.jpg';
$filename = basename($file);
$data = [
    'uploaded_file' => curl_file_create($file, 'image/jpeg', $filename),
];
$ch = curl_init();   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

or just encode file with MIME base64 ([base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) function) and include it as API param:

```
$file = '/foo/bar/img.jpg';
$imagedata = file_get_contents($file);
$base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Input::file('nameOfParameterGet')
You can get an array of files to.